# Novella about meat creatures from another dimension that are released by Nazi magic

Tags: story-identification, books, magic, nazis

I can remember quite a bit about this novella, but I can't find it again and it's driving me nuts.

Pretty sure it was published before 2000, but I am not sure; I know a man wrote it.

Two college kids find a magic Nazi book filled with advanced math and such that they use, via a rabbit, to open a portal to another dimension that these meat-eating creatures can come through. They are hostile to humans and kill any they come across, often grafting them with with local animals and other people.

A professor reads the book and goes insane.

A police offer sees the face of his son grafted onto a rabbit's body at one point.

The two men track down the Nazi doctor in an insane asylum, leave with the cop and go to the mine where the creatures are creating an orgy soup and a portal to fully open them up to Earth. The police officer sacrifices himself with the bomb, but saves everyone.

I should have most of the details right, but I haven't read it in a few years. Please help; it's driving me nuts and I wanna reread it.

Pretty sure the title had the word Rabbit in it.

Comment: A meat monster makes me think of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Dies_at_the_End but I don't think the other details match up.

Comment: No I;m sorry I def know its not John dies at the end

Comment: In roughly which year did you actually read this? And do you recall anything about the cover?

Comment: I read it at least 10 years ago and I read it as a PDF online and I think I remember a rabbit on the cover page

Comment: Oh, those naughty Nazis. Always up to mischief

Comment: Nazis, magic from mathematics, and other dimensions, makes me think of Charlie Stross's Laundry series, but I don't think any of those involve children or face grafting.